# Why is this UrlFetch function not working properly?

Tags: javascript, fetch, urlfetch

This is the function I'm trying to run through the JavaScript Tool on my Google Spreadsheet chart, the function is currently working on 4 different websites, where in this example:

$id is the imported value from my spreadsheet cell (belacoin)

```
function CoinmarketcapPrice($id) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/" + $id);
  var html = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  try 
  {
    return parseFloat(html["price_btc"]);
  }
  catch(err)
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

this is what that UrlFetch returns:

```
[
    {
        "id": "belacoin", 
        "name": "BelaCoin", 
        "symbol": "BELA", 
        "rank": "176", 
        "price_usd": "0.212823", 
        "price_btc": "0.00008400", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "534995.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "7694903.0", 
        "available_supply": "36156350.0", 
        "total_supply": "36156350.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "0.63", 
        "percent_change_24h": "1.88", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-17.03", 
        "last_updated": "1499549044"
    }
]
```

Comment: What is it doing wrong?

Comment: it's not returning me the "price_btc" that I wish to acquire...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try html.price_btc or html[0].price_btc

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that endpoint is returning an array of objects, so if you want to access the first item in the array change your try block to:

```
try {
  return parseFloat(html[0]["price_btc"]);
}
```

Comment: hi there, thanks for your quick reply, but it's still not working =/
I tried: html[0]["price_btc"], html[6]["price_btc"], html["price_btc"][0] and html[6]. None of them worked...

Comment: @Thales454 It should work if the JSON is as you show above. What does `console.log(html[0])` show?

Answer (score 0):

```
return html[0].price_btc;
```

made it work, thank you all!