# Why is this UrlFetch function not working properly? 2.0

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, fetch, google-sheets-api, urlfetch

This is the function I'm trying to run through the JavaScript Tool on my Google Spreadsheet chart, I've got a very similar function currently working on another website, which I've previously solved it's issue on this topic:
[Why is this UrlFetch function not working properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44997630/why-is-this-urlfetch-function-not-working-properly)

But altough this looks very similar, I can't get it to work...

$id is the imported value from my spreadsheet cell (BTC_BELA)

```
function NovaexchangePrice($id) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://novaexchange.com/remote/v2/markets/");
  var html = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  try 
  {
    return parseFloat(html['markets']["last_price"]);
  }
  catch(err)
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

I've currently tried the following:

```
return parseFloat(html['markets'].last_price);
return parseFloat(html[2].last_price);
return parseFloat(html.markets[1]);
```

This is what that UrlFetch (https://novaexchange.com/remote/v2/markets/) returns:

```
{"status": "success", "message": "Markets listed at Novaexchange", "markets":
 [{"bid": "0.00000602", "last_price": "0.00000600", "volume24h": "0.333", "marketid": 7539, "disabled": 1, "currency": "4CHN", "marketname": "BTC_4CHN", "ask": "0.00001000", "low24h": "0.00000600", "change24h": "-64.7", "high24h": "0.00001700", "basecurrency": "BTC"},
 {"bid": "0.00000000", "last_price": "0.00000001", "volume24h": "0.000", "marketid": 7347, "disabled": 1, "currency": "SPRT", "marketname": "BTC_SPRT", "ask": "0.00000001", "low24h": "0.00000001", "change24h": "0.0", "high24h": "0.00000001", "basecurrency": "BTC"},
 {"bid": "0.00000000", "last_price": "0.00000001", "volume24h": "0.000", "marketid": 7359, "disabled": 1, "currency": "XPZ", "marketname": "BTC_XPZ", "ask": "0.00000004", "low24h": "0.00000001", "change24h": "0.0", "high24h": "0.00000001", "basecurrency": "BTC"},
... and so on.
```

Comment: Are you asking how to access the last_price attribute on that is json?

Comment: correct! sorry if I didn't make it clear enough =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try `html.markets[0].last_price`?

edit:

If you're just looking for one market in particular, you could do a forEach loop through the array of markets like so:

```
html.markets.forEach(function(entry) {
    if (entry.marketname == "BTC_BELA") {
        console.log(entry.last_price);
    }
});
```

Though it might be better to reassign each entry to a keyed object for easier access:

```
var obj = {};
html.markets.forEach(function(entry) {
    var marketname = entry.marketname;
    obj[marketname] = entry;
});

console.log(obj["BTC_BELA"].last_price);
```

Comment: yes, and it returned me: 0.000016 for all currencies :P
(which is incorrect)

Comment: change the number in brackets to move between markets

Comment: it acquired the last_price of the first market (BTC_4CHN)
how am I going to make it search for the BTC_BELA market and then return last_price?

I tried:
`return parseFloat(html.markets[$id].last_price);`
but it didn't work...

Comment: ok, I'll try to make a while loop that matches "currency" then return me "last_price" =)

Comment: I did a very simple loop:

`var loop = true;
    var match = 0;
    while(loop)
    {
      if(parseFloat(html.markets[match].marketname) == $id)
      {
        loop = false;
        return parseFloat(html.markets[match].last_price);
      }
      else match++
    }`

the problem (at the moment) is that:
`return parseFloat(html.markets[0].marketname);`

is not even returning me it's market name (which should be BTC_4CHN)

Comment: damn, my comment looks like crap once I hit Enter... I'm pretty new to this forum, how do I structure my answer properly? :x

Comment: thanks your help! the code:

`for (x in html.markets)
    {if (html.markets[x].marketname == $id) return html.markets[x].last_price;}`

got it working!